# XAMPP on Vista not executing my own PHP files

Tags: xampp, windows-vista

I installed xampp on a machine with vista business SP1 version. The default page (with the "You have successfully installed XAMPP on this system" message) opens up fine.

But when I put a php page in the htdocs folder and try to access it using 127.0.0.1/mypage.php, I get the "Object not found" error.. The apache service is running as indicated by XAMPP Control Panel. I clicked the "Port-Check" button on the xampp control panel and this what it says:

```
Apache(HTTP) 80 System
```

I checked with a XP machine and it says:

```
Apache(HTTP) 80 C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe
```

How do I resolve this issue? I have disabled windows firewall and UAC.

Comment: What do you see when you click on "Status" on the left hand side of http://127.0.0.1/xampp/?  Is PHP activated or not?

Comment: yes PHP is activated.. This has got me flummoxed..

Comment: @JimFerrans: PHP has to be enabled (activated and working), if XAMPP Welcome Screen works fine. It uses PHP.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think there are some problems with your PHP interpreter, as XAMPP Welcome Screen works fine and it uses PHP.

Form the fact, that you put PHP file into htdocs and can't access it via browser plus the fact that your "port-check" shows some strange entries, I assume that you have another installation of Apache on your system or that you have a web server component enabled in your system. Information dumped from port-check clearly says that you have some system service listening on port 80, which seems to be capturing all the request before Apache on-board your XAMPP can handle it. But, on the other hand, how then you would be able to run XAMPP Welcome Screen? Really strange situation.

As first step, I would recommend doing extensive research through all your active services (run "services.msc"), installed programs and enabled system components (both in Control Panel section responsible for handling program and sys comps). Disable or uninstall everything that seems to be related to web server.

If this brings no effect, then you should address your question to a StackExchange sister project called "ServerFault", because this seems to purely server or system related question, not belonging to XAMPP discussed on StackOverflow.